# How can I draw a scalable field of Hexagons with Java 3D?

Tags: java-3d

I'd like to draw a scalable field of hexagons with java3d.

I'm new to java3d so i looked up the documentation. As far is I know there is no direct way to paint something like that. I found the possibility to draw an triangle. Is there a way to combine two of them to a hexagon, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a polygon, look at [this example](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=ojruj2e20jjfhcfe79ert2t7g0&topic=1024.msg9275#msg9275). You have to create a GeometryInfo instance by using GeometryInfo.POLYGON_ARRAY to indicate you're going to build a polygon. Then, put your vertices into it and build a Shape3D with the geometry array of your GeometryInfo instance.

By the way, check that you use the latest version of [Java 3D](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Java3D_FAQ) (currently 1.6.0).